# Determining if field is NULL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, odbc

I'm working on an MFC app which does database access using CDatabase and CRecordset classes. The database is not dynamically bound to an MFC-based form or window.

I'm having an issue with detecting when a particular field of a record is NULL.

Most of my code is working fine. I have no problem connecting to the database, issuing queries, and reading back records.  However, there are a couple of fields where I am getting garbage strings, and when I check the database it shows me that the fields in question are NULL.

NULL is reasonable in some cases, so rather than preventing it, I need my code to simply handle it correctly.  The values returned from **GetFieldValue** for the fields in question are **NOT** null, however. I get some random value that is not a valid pointer.  Apparently I need to do some sort of test-for-NULL that isn't simply checking the pointer value.

There is a method in the **CRecordset** class called **IsFieldNull** but it doesn't seem to work right, or I'm not calling it properly. I've found no good examples online for how this method is used.  The documentation says it takes a single parameter, a void pointer that points to a "field data member" but there's no definition of what that's supposed to be.  I've seen examples where a zero-based field index is passed, and examples where a string constant with the field name is passed. I've tried both of these ideas and neither seems to work.

In fact, calling CRecordset::IsFieldNull() **always** makes my code fly off into never-never land.

There is another member of CRecordset called **IsFieldStatusNull** which is allegedly supposed to take a field index, but I've found that calling it also fails.

Ultimately, my question is, how does one check if a particular field in a CRecordset is NULL?

---

I don't really think the existing code is relevant to the question but since it's been requested, here it is (simplified to remove the try/catch block):

```
CDBVariant v;
CRecordset theRecordSet(&theDB); // Pointer to my CDatabase object
query.Format("SELECT B.*, B.photographerWebsite AS website FROM gbm_shootphotographers AS A INNER JOIN gbm_photographers AS B ON A.photographerID=B.photographerID WHERE A.shootID=%d;", shootID );  
BOOL result = theRecordSet.Open(AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE, query );
memset(&v,0,sizeof(CDBVariant)); // Zero it out before retrieving field
// 1
theRecordSet.GetFieldValue("website", v);
// 2
CString website = *v.m_pstring;
```

For records where the "website" field has data, it's retrieved just fine. The string is exactly as expected. However, for records where "website" is NULL, I"m getting a non-empty string with garbage, or even worse, a bad string pointer. Frankly, I don't understand why it outputs *anything* to the CDBVariant object for a NULL field, but therein lies the problem.

I've tried calling **IsFieldNull** and **IsFieldStatusNull** at both location #1 and location #2. Goes off into the weeds either way.

Comment: A pointer that is not `==NULL` (or, better, `==nullptr`), is not a NULL field. If odbc produces values supposed to be NULL but `!=nullptr` then something's broken about it or the way it handles NULL. Or, more likely, you're reading from some location that's not valid in the first place, but of which the database somehow knows that all fields in it are NULL.

Comment: Can you show us how you do a query, and fetch/use the data?

Comment: @leftaroundabout - A 'null' in a database record is not at all the same thing as a 'null' pointer, and it doesn't mean "zero".  

In this particular case, the structure that receives the data is zeroed out BEFORE the field is retrieved, and the retrieval proceeds without error.  The result is a non-zero value, but if you look at the the database using SQL Server Management Studio, you see the field is NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before accessing data in `CDBVariant` you must check its `m_dwType` member.

- `m_pstring` is only valid for access when type is `DBVT_STRING`
- when DB field is null, variant will be `DBVT_NULL` and no member is valid for access
- etc, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4hhd4f44(v=vs.80)

CDBVariant is a `union`, which means though technically you can read any member at any time, reading the one you're not supposed to read results in undefined behavior. In your case, you're getting random pointer which may print to garbage string, or crash right away.

Comment: Thanks much! Just the info I needed! I know about the union stuff but couldn't figure out how to ensure the data was valid.

I was also stuck on the fact that the **IsFieldNull** stuff wasn't working. I've traced through the source code and determined that call is apparantly **only** for when you have the recordset bound to the UI controls, even though the documentation doesn't really spell that out.

For some reason, the built-in help for CDBVariant does not include all the same info that's on the web page you linked. Most notably, the **m_dwType** value is not described.

Thanks again!